# Confusing clojure macro var evaluation

Tags: macros, clojure

I am trying to write a clojure macro that transforms clojure keywords to java enums. But the evaluation of the parameters in a macro is confusing:

```
user=> (defmacro show-and-tell [thing]
#_=>   `(vector ~(name thing) ~(type thing) ~thing))
#'user/show-and-tell
user=> (macroexpand-1 (show-and-tell :foo))
["foo" clojure.lang.Keyword :foo]
user=> (def foo :bar)
#'user/foo
user=> (name foo)
"bar"
user=> (type foo)
clojure.lang.Keyword
user=> (macroexpand-1 (show-and-tell foo))
["foo" clojure.lang.Symbol :bar]
```

So it works as I would expect if the keyword is provided directly as a parameter. But if it is a var, I don't get the correct `name` and `type` of the thingy.

I can make it 'sort-of-almost' work by using eval:

```
user=> (defmacro show-and-tell-with-eval [thing]
  #_=>   `(vector ~(name (eval thing)) ~(type (eval thing)) ~(eval thing)))
#'user/show-and-tell-with-eval
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(show-and-tell-with-eval foo))
(clojure.core/vector "bar" clojure.lang.Keyword :bar)
user=> (let [baz :bar-foo] (macroexpand-1 '(show-and-tell baz)))
(clojure.core/vector "baz" clojure.lang.Symbol baz)
user=> (let [baz :bar-foo] (macroexpand-1 '(show-and-tell-with-eval baz)))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: baz in this context
```

Can someone explain this to me? Is there no way to see the `name` of a (local) var inside a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanted to write

```
(defmacro show-and-tell [thing] `(vector (name ~thing) (type ~thing) ~thing))
```

Ad-hoc explanation:

The key to understand what's going on is to know *when* the arguments are evaluated. Macros take unevaluated data structures as arguments and return a data structure which is then evaluated using the rules above. Using the `~` you tell the compiler which data structures should be evaluated at runtime, thus, your `thing` argument, not the return value of `(name thing)` value as the `thing` value will be bound at compile time in the latter case which is not what you wanted

Here you have a further explanation about writing macros http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/

Comment: Ahh, luckily us simple minds make simple errors. Thank you, that of course fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the relation between vars and what they contain and how macros come into play. "Vars provide a mechanism to refer to a mutable storage location" (cf. the [offical docs on Vars](http://clojure.org/vars)). When you evaluate `foo` in the REPL, Clojure will evaluate it according to the rules outlined in the [offical docs for evaluation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) which in this case means, it *resolves* the symbol to "the value of the binding of the global var named by the symbol".

Now, it's crucial to understand that macros "are functions that manipulate forms, allowing for syntactic abstraction". Basically macros allow direct access to any parameter handed to the macro and then manipulate and evaluate the related data as needed. Let's take a glance at your macro and what happens in your "erroneous" case:

```
(defmacro show-and-tell [thing]
  `(vector ~(name thing) ~(type thing) ~thing))
```

Your macro definition gets fed some `thing` (whatever is the parameter to `show-and-tell`). At this point, `thing` will *not* be resolved. Only in your macro definition you have some evaluations. Please note that in this call, you're calling `macroexpand-1` on the (evaluated) *result* of `(show-and-tell foo)` which is probably not what you want:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 (show-and-tell foo))
["foo" clojure.lang.Symbol :bar]
```

Quoting the call shows what's going on:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(show-and-tell foo))
(clojure.core/vector "foo" clojure.lang.Symbol foo)
```

You're calling `vector` with "foo" (i.e. the `name` of `foo`) where `foo` is a symbol and then your code will resolve `foo` normally (and give `:bar`).

From your description, you seem to expect that normal symbol resolution will take place for all your arguments. *If this is what you want, you don't need a macro in the first place.* But just for the record, by now it should be obvious what you need to do: you need to evalute `thing` first (which is pretty much what you did with `eval`). In other words, you placed your `unquote` operator wrong:

```
(defmacro show-and-tell [thing]
  `(vector (name ~thing) (type ~thing) ~thing))
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(show-and-tell foo))
(clojure.core/vector (clojure.core/name foo) (clojure.core/type foo) foo)
user=> (show-and-tell foo)
["bar" clojure.lang.Keyword :bar]
```